# Monopoly Players VS Chess Players

Tags: riddle

Once upon a time, there were two **Billionaire Brothers** who had a lot of money to waste. One of them proposed to hold a competition in one of their houses. The other brother agreed with this so they placed posters all around town to invite people to join their competition.

The next month there were a total of 467 people who attended the competition. The attendees were given the choice to join either a monopoly competition or a chess competition. The competitions were held in two rooms of the house, one room for the monopoly players and one room for the chess players. The brothers attended both games as judges and both of them remained in a third room which had walls filled with screens containing a continuous camera feed of both competitions. Only 152 people went to Chess while the rest went to Monopoly.

I want you to figure out how many people joined the ***Competition of Monopoly***?

---

**Optional**

> In your opinion which game is better?

Comment: "There were two rooms in the house" - "both of them remained in the third room". Is this a mistake or part of the riddle?

Comment: The title is a bit misleading, both brothers are according to your story in the third room so that would be 2 but your question asks how many people are playing monopoly.

Comment: @kl78 its part of riddle

Comment: @MarcoGeertsma pls change the title to what u think is appropriate

Comment: I would change the title to something along the lines of "How many people are playing monopoly?" or "Monopoly players vs chess players". I do agree with @kl78 though, if the third room is part of the riddle and my answer is not the right one, could you please clarify what we're missing?

Comment: Linguistically, there are a lot of things a bit weird. The first is the 2 vs 3 rooms, which was mentioned to be intentional. Then there's a competition, which is then called a game, which consists of two competitions. There are screens filled with cameras, rather than video images (from cameras). The Competition of Monopoly could be the same as the Monopoly Competition, but it's not truly a given. And waste money? Should that be money to waste or did they earn the money in the waste management? I suppose not all of that is intentional...

Comment: Oh, and the chess is in one. One something, but it's not entirely clear one what.

Comment: Amm anything else u want me to make better?

Comment: Since you marked an answer as correct I tried making the question more grammatically correct. Please correct me if I edited something I shouldn't have.

Comment: its better than my dumb grammar and i have no objections with ur edits

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My answer is

> 313
>  (467 - 2 brothers) - 152

---

Since OP stated that the third room predicament was intentional and part of the question I'm adding another possible solution

My answer for the title question

> 2, since only the two brothers are in the third room to observe the others.

Answer (score 0):

Stuck mid-way

> Excluding the brothers, there are 465-152 = 313 people. Since monopoly is game of 2-8 players so considering each game includes all 8 players, then 1 player will not able to play so 312 people.

---

> The same scenario works if for each game maximum 2, 3, 4, 6 or 8 players are allowed and still there will be 1 player who will not be able to play

---

> However, this theory does not work if each game has maximum 5 and 7 players.

Answer (score 0):

**Optional**

> I Prefer Monopoly Rather Then Chess